# When I use Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (Ubuntu built into Windows 10), where is my Windows root filesystem (e.g. C drive)?

Tags: command-line, windows, filesystem

When I use "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" (the Ubuntu built into Windows 10), what directory accesses my Windows filesystem (e.g. C drive, My Documents, etc.)?

For example, my username is "ed" so when I start bash I'm in: /home/ed

I want to be able to access something like:

- C:\Windows
- C:\Users\Ed\Documents

Where do I find the root Windows filesystem in the bash shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by searching for files that existed in my documents on the Ubuntu bash command line using "locate." Yay!

- /mnt/c/Windows
- /mnt/c/Users/Ed/Documents
- /mnt/d/...

Answer (score 1):

use df at the Ubuntu bash prompt to read the mount point (below "/") of your file systems ("C:", etc).

For those (like me) wondering where the "/home" is in Windows, it's here :
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited*\LocalState\rootfs\home